# The relation between the projection matrix and the original matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

I am confused about the relation between the projection matrix and its original matrix. Suppose I have a matrix $A_{m \times n}, m \ne n$ , then its projection matrix is $P=A(A^TA)^{-1}A^T$. From Strang's book, what $P$ does is to project a vector, say $\textbf{b}$, into the column space of $A$, i.e., $C(A)$. In addition, by the matrix-vector operation, $P\textbf{b}$ can be interpreted as putting $\textbf{b}$ to the column space of $P$, i.e., $C(P)$, since $P\textbf{b}$ represents the linear combination of the column vectors of $P$.

So, does

1. $C(P)=C(A)$? and
2. $P$ contain the basis for $C(A)$?

Edit: According to the answer provided by @Ben Grossmann, an appropriate way to describe the second question may be "does the column vectors of $P$ span $C(A)$"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, note that in order for $(A^TA)^{-1}$ to be defined, we must have $m\geq n$. and $A$ must have linearly independent columns.

1. Yes, it is true that $C(P) = C(A)$.
2. Your question does not make sense as stated: we cannot talk about "the basis" because a space generally has infinitely many bases, and a matrix does not "contain" vectors. However, it is true that the columns of $P$ span $C(A)$, and a basis for $C(A)$ may be extracted from the columns of $P$.

Note, however, that the column-space of a transformation does not give you as much information as you might expect. For example, in the case where $A$ is square we find that $P = I$.  Knowing $P$ only tells us that $A$ is an invertible linear transformation.

Comment: Sincerely appreciate your answer! I especially like the fact that you point out my terminology issue!

Comment: @WeiziLi You're welcome. Regarding your edit: note that if $m < n$, then $P$ will not have linearly independent columns, so it is not true that the columns of $P$ form a basis.

Comment: by any chance, your original answer misplaced $m$ and $n$? I assumed the dimension of $A$ is $m \times n$, so if $m < n$, we won't have $n$ independent column vectors for sure, thus we cannot really define $(A^TA)^{-1}$. In other words, in order for $(A^TA)^{-1}$ to be defined, we would require $m \ge n$ and $A$ must have linearly independent columns. For example, when $A=[1,0,0]^T$, $(A^TA)^{-1}=1$ (defined).

Comment: In addition, thank you for pointing out that when $m < n$ (this case I think the relation is correct), $P$ will not have linearly independent columns. So, it is not true that the columns of $P$ form a basis. My follow-up question is what is the correct way to state this? "the columns of $P$ contain a basis for $C(A)$"? not sure which verb to use here. Please advise!

Comment: @Weizi That's correct

Comment: @WeiziLi Usually we would say "the columns of $P$ span $C(A)$".

Comment: Got it, thank you very much!